# Switching between apps in same platform using xamarin Implimentation

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a question in mobile apps using Xamarin. Suppose i have implemented 2 Apps like App1 and App2 in same platform(Exp - Android).

As per the business scenario From the App1 I need to switch to App2 in same platform(Assume both apps deployed in android device). But I am not sure how to do this using the Xamarin. Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to open App2 in App1 ?If yes

Here are several methods for it:

(1)use package name, specific Activity name pulled up

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
/** knows the packet life to jump to and the target Activity*/
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(package name, class name);//e.g ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("kuyu.com.xxxx", "kuyu.com.xxxx.xxx.login.WelcomeActivity");
intent.SetComponent(componentName);
StartActivity(intent);
```

App2 needs to be added in the manifest file corresponding to the Activity:

```
android:exported="true"
```

(2) the package name is pulled up (this is going into the startup page)

```
Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(package name);//e.g Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("kuyu.com.xxxx");
   if (intent != null)
        {
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

(3) url pull up (which as the answer above)

Answer (score -1):

using Xamarin.Essentials;
await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred); }

Or

https://xamarinhelp.com/launching-mobile-app-via-uri-scheme/

I think this will help, and look deep linking in Xamarin :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25351227)

Comment: I edit it but every code may be duplicate and every link may be expire :)))